# LINQ Query C# ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

In English I'm trying to: "Return a list of People who don't have the TeamID in their List of Teams

I have a many-to-many relationship between a Person table and a Team table so each instance of a Person has a List of Teams that they are a member of. (each Team also has a list of People)

[image: Table]

*here a Person 2 would have a list of two Team objects with ID's of 1 and 2*

I'm trying to write a query that, if TeamID were 18 it would return only Persons 1 and 3 for example

This is my attempt:

```
var query = from p in db.People
            where( query2 = from t in p.Teams
                            where t.ID != teamID
                            select t)
            select p;
```

Comment: This is a bad title. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Sorry it's a bit generic, how could I be more specific in the title?

Comment: 1) your requirement seems to be different from the query you have provided OR they are not very clear

2) your nested query is selecting 't' but not giving true or false (because where clause is meant to return true or false)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the method-based LINQ syntax this becomes:

```
var query = db.People.Where(p => !p.Teams.Any(t => t.ID == 18));
```

Comment: You can also use `db.People.Where(p => p.Teams.All(t => t.ID != 18))` if you find that more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted to your code:

```
var query =    
        from p in db.People
        where !(from t in db.Teams    
                select t.ID)    
               .Contains(p.ID)    
        select p;
```